# How do you programmatically tell if an Eclipse plug-in makes a UI contribution?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

How do I programmatically tell if an Eclipse plug-in does/does not make a UI contribution to Eclipse?

Specifically, I have access to a p2 repository, and I want to be able to tell which of the plug-ins in the repository do or do not make a UI contribution.

Or if is there any other way not via the p2 (e.g. via BundleContext)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two differences between UI and Non-UI plugins:

1. UI plugins depend on other UI plugins and transitively depend on the SWT plugin
2. UI plugin activators sub-class from `org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin`, whereas non-UI plugin activators typically sub-class from `org.eclipse.core.runtime.Plugin`.

If you are trying to analyze a p2 repository, then you should be looking for #1.  Check all of the transitive dependencies for org.eclipse.swt.